# On a normal standard die one of the $21$ dots from any one of the six faces is removed at random with each dot equally likely to be chosen.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

On a normal standard die one of the $21$ dots from any one of the six faces is removed at random with each dot equally likely to be chosen.The die is then rolled.Prove that the probability that the top face has an odd number of dots is $\frac{11}{21}.$

---

Since one of the 21 dots is removed,so either the face having 6 dots become 5 dotted face or the face having 5 dots become 4 dotted face or the face having 4 dots become 3 dotted face or the face having 3 dots become 2 dotted face or the face having 2 dots become 1 dotted face or the face having 1 dot become 0 dotted face.

Probability that the face having 6 dots become 5 dotted face$=\frac{6}{21}$
Probability that the face having 4 dots become 3 dotted face$=\frac{4}{21}$
Probability that the face having 2 dots become 1 dotted face$=\frac{2}{21}$

Now the probability of top face having an odd number of dots is$\frac{1}{2}\times \left(\frac{6}{21}+\frac{4}{21}+\frac{2}{21}\right)$

But this does not give me the correct answer.Where have i gone wrong?Please help me.

Comment: You haven't considered all the cases like 5 dots face becoming 4 dots. Draw a full tree diagram and see what's happening in each case. Multiply and add the probabilities appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You went wrong on the line beginning with "Now the probability $\ldots$". Actually I cannot see how you arrived at the formula with the $\times$.

I'd argue  as follows: With probability ${6\over21}+{4\over21}+{2\over21}={4\over7}$ you change an "even face" to an "odd face" and therewith create a die having four "odd faces", and with probability ${5\over21}+{3\over21}+{1\over21}={3\over7}$ you change an "odd face" to an "even face" and therewith create a die having only two "odd faces". The probability that, after the die has been thrown, the top face has an odd number of eyes is therefore given by
$${4\over7}\cdot{2\over3}+{3\over7}\cdot{1\over3}={11\over21}\ .$$

Comment: Sir have you counted $0$ as even or odd?@Christian Blatter

Comment: When you count the face having $0$ dots as odd numbered face,then only this answer is possible.But i think $0$ is considered an even number.@Christian Blatter

Comment: All people consider $0$ as an even number, and it is considered even in the above answer.

Comment: I understood your logic sir.Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry it clicked me late.

Comment: In questions like this, it slightly baffles me that the actual number of outcomes remains 6, so the probability to sample an odd number of $\frac{4}{6}$, not $\frac{3}{5}$.